# Seudas Pidyon HaBen and Bris Milah together

Tags: brit-milah, meal-seudah, simchah-joy-happiness, pidyon-haben

If someone had a baby boy and the bris was pushed off until what came out to be the day of the Pidyon HaBen. Can the 2 seudas, one for the Bris and the other for the Pidyon HaBen be made together as one seudas mitzvah? Or is this a problem of being "marvin simcha b'simcha (mixing together 2 separate simchas.) Are there any sources on this?

(Related: [Question of which to make first, the bris or the pidyon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9150/when-a-bris-is-being-done-for-a-baby-at-the-same-time-as-his-pidyon-haben))

Comment: I've heard that these 2 seudas are not considered enough of a "simcha" to be a problem of "ain marvin..." A wedding is considered a simcha or a seudas yom tov (this is the classifc example of ain marvin...)

Answer (score 1):

[Sefer Yismach Lev Volume 4 / Page 92](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51632&st=&pgnum=120&hilite=) brings from [Tosfos Moed Kattan 8b - Mipnei Bitul Pirya V'Rivya](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9689&st=&pgnum=16) that one may make a Bris on Chol HaMoed as it is not considered a Simcha as there is pain for the circumcised child.

He says that Tosfos finishes and says that there is no issue of mixing Simchas only by weddings.

Comment: Isnt a chasson and Yom tov dealing with the same person?

Comment: @Sam - I believe my edit takes care of your issue.

Comment: Very interesting take ,makes sense since we learn it from Yaakov, but I did find those who dont allow by purim and chol hamoed,seems to be related to the bracha of שהשמחה במעונו...

Comment: @Sam - However the question here was specific to Bris and Pidyon HaBen together and this answers it with a source.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Eliyashiv in Ashrei HaIsh YD page 157 is quoted that it is permissible and does not consider it an issue.

Text:

[image]

Comment: I will try and find his reasoning why its not an issue,but for now that was his psak

Comment: If it's not a simcha to mess with chol hamoed then it's probably not a simcha to mess with milah (and vice versa, so it comes out neither is a 'simcha' regarding this rule).

Comment: The issue is that not everyone holds like this ,see Shu"t Mahari Weil 189 and Mahari Bruna 121 that one should not mix pidyon haben with chol hamoed and purim...